# what is disadvantage to send small Ethernet frame less than 64 bytes?

Tags: linux, sockets, ethernet

I am working on a Linux project. My program communicate with another machine with raw socket, and I notice there are some small Ethernet frame less than 64 bytes. I know that minimal Ethernet frame size is 64 bytes, and it is because of collision-detect mechanism. I want to make sure if there is any problem to send and receive small frame packets, or will it cause some potential problem?

Comment: They are simply padded to 64.

Comment: I use wireshark to capture the frame, and frame size is less than 64.

Comment: You [might want to check out info like this, then](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/internetworking/troubleshooting/guide/tr1904.html) Runt frames should not be happening regularly.

Comment: I've never seen a padded frame in wireshark. It's possible that wireshark just [strips the padding](http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q7.10) before presenting the data. Although [Possibly Related](http://serverfault.com/questions/510657/is-the-64-byte-minimal-ethernet-packet-rule-respected-in-practice) maybe not.

Comment: @Serdalis Hmm... I swear I saw some recently when diagnosing something. Although, it occurs to me *maybe it wasn't Wireshark*!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Completely possible, I suppose the answer to his question is, don't worry about your packet sizes, the Ethernet card / driver will pad them / de-pad them for you... as long as you keep Nagels algorithm on for TCP when sending many small packets there should be little detrement.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so people can see this has been answered then. Glad I could help.